# Angular 2: Retrieve objects from firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Below is my firebase database screenshot:
[image]

Below is the code in the "app.component":

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from "angularfire2/database-deprecated";
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Component ....

items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

constructor(public af: AngularFireDatabase) {
   this.items = af.list('/projects', {
     query: {
       limitToLast: 10
     }
   });
   console.log(this.items);
}
```

but I'm not getting the data. Could anyone help me out on this?

I've completed the angularfire2 setup and able to write the data to the real time database. It's the issue with getting the data from db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call a subscribe method on the list. As such:

```
this.items = af.list('/projects').valueChanges().subscribe(items => {
    console.log(items);
}));
```

I see that u are using a the `database-deprecated` package. The code should be as such:

```
this.firebaseList = af.list('/projects'); // This is of type FirebaseListObservable

this.items = this.firebaseList.subscribe(items => {
    console.log(items);
})); // This is of type subscription.

this.firebaseList.push({...data}); // Now you can push.
```

Comment: I changed it to:

items: Observable<any[]>;
  
  constructor(public af: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items = af.list('/projects').subscribe(items => {
      console.log(items);
    });
  }

but it says, Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[]>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.
(property) AddProjectComponent.items: Observable<any[]>

Comment: PERFECT!! It works now. But, now I'm not able to push: this.items.push(form.value). It says: Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Subscription'.

Comment: You are my Hero. Thank you!

Comment: @StanvanHeumen your code is perfect for fetching all data and print in console but think if I have to find the 
key:
       accountDetials:
                                mail

from above pic 
In this how can i print the value of mail